# Why is checking MD5 hash important

Tags: download, md5

Oftentimes when you download a file, the site offering the download will list the MD5 hash for the file being downloaded.

But I've never had a problem with getting a bad download. In fact, I thought that since FTP was a TCP protocol, you couldn't get bad downloads.

Is there any data on how often bad downloads occur (i.e. when checking the MD5 hash tells you the download is bad)?

Comment: maybe a bad person changed the file but not the md5 sum

Answer (score 4):

It's not so much a problem with the TCP/IP protocol accidentally swapping a bit (although that DID happen sometimes in the old days, it's not much a concern now).

MD5 is especially helpful when downloading a file from a mirror site.  For example, getting an ISO for a new OS.  The original site can give you the MD5, and then you can download the ISO from another company.  To make sure that mirror has not tampered with the image at all, you can use the MD5.

In summary, MD5 is to validate the *authenticity* of the file - that may or may not mean a hardware level mishap.  Usually it's something a bit more intentional and mischievous.

Answer (score 0):

It is not for bad downloads mostly it is for verifying authenticity of downloadable to ensure that no one has tampered the downloadable.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the file is outside of webserver you are connected to. The website has information about checksum, file size, file name.
When user has no assurance, that the file could be replaced with one which looks the same, but has some additional features, like malware, wrong mine-type, you can check check-sum to be sure about that.